# Building a survey to put in a WordPress website using Python/Django

Tags: python, django

So I've been given a task to build a survey to get data regarding time slot preferences of prospective students for a particular course. I know there are really quick solutions to this like Google Forms, SurveyMonkey, but since it's not unusually hard, I want to implement the survey myself in a totally new language as an opportunity to get started with it and also be able to customize and provide dynamic info to the users who are voting.

Although I have done some stuff in PHP, C++, javascript, etc, I'm pretty new to Python+Django framework but it's something I've been meaning to get into since a long time ago.

Initially, what I want is to make a grid with the days of the week as columns and time-durations as rows. In each cell I want to provide users a way to choose how strong (high/medium/low) their preference for this particular day+time is. I also want to show how many "votes" have already been cast for this particular preference because this will influence a lot in their decisions and as a result make this process easier when we are going to define the classes.
I'll probably store the data in MySQL.

Could anyone point me to some really good Python+Django tutorials for my particular purpose?
Does anyone think I'm wasting my time with this trivial task by choosing new tools and that I should just use something I already know (like PHP) or a free service or plugin for Wordpress?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF YOU WANT TO LEARN DJANGO itself:**
Some of the machinery you need It's part ot the basic tutorial you can find inside the official Django documentation: the [**Poll**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/) app.

There is also a [**Django Survey**](http://code.google.com/p/django-survey/) project on google code

**IF YOU WANT A CLOUD (free or cheap) SERVICE:**
In this case I'd like to point you to [**Wufoo**](http://wufoo.com/signup/) that is a very nice web form builder which have also a FREE plan with report and notifications (by mail, SMS or web hooks). It's very easy to integrate and the only hassle you will get is to retrieve the poll results from them. They provide a lot of way to export them and offer also a very simple API.

Answer (score 0):

The [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com) is a  good starting point, together with the documentation on the Django site itself.

Integrating it into Wordpress could be more complicated, if you need tight integration I would not use a different language.

And in general I would never say that learing a new and different language is a waste of time, and Django is a pretty nice Framework.